# http request edit for originating IP

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I have an website where i wan to show a add w.r.t. city. So in my code i am taking the IP from the request object and calculate the city from [MaxMind GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/csv) database. Now i wan to test this. can somebody tell how can i test for different city, i can't move across cities an test. Can we do some TCP packet edit so that my server code will get different different ip for the same client and  i can test for variety of IPs or some tools. Thanks!!

Comment: what I would do for testing purpose is define a test array with several Ip's in it (Ip's you know which city they are from), and use data from this array (or even file actually) instead of data from the request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your code to layers.

1. Very thin HTTP layer that extracts the IP
2. Layer that gets IP and returns city.

Now you can create separate unit tests for each layer (one that simulates HTTP requests and checks that the IP address is extracted correctly, second for the business logic) and probably one integration test that performs real HTTP request from one predefined known location and check that you get correct city.

BTW the first layer (that extracts IP address) actually consists of one line like `request.getRemoteAddr()`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about different IP's for your test,  but i am suggesting you to Use `geoip` for your need

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<br>Country Code:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_country_code());</script>
<br>Country Name:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_country_name());</script>
<br>City:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>
<br>Region:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region());</script>
<br>Region Name:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region_name());</script>
<br>Latitude:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_latitude());</script>
<br>Longitude:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_longitude());</script>
<br>Postal Code:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_postal_code());</script>
```